# What is the earliest source mentioning that Jews put out greenery on Shavuos?

Tags: minhag, shavuos, agriculture

What is the earliest source mentioning the Minhag that Jews put out greenery on Shavuos?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7848/why-do-we-put-out-greenery-on-shavuos)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35991&st=&pgnum=26

Hebrew translation

ויאמר המן למלך אחשורוש, שמנהג היהודים שעולים לבתי מקדש מעט שלהם ומשליכים פרחי שושנים ותפוחים ומלקטים אותם ואומרים זה היום שניתנה התורה לאבותינו בהר סיני

תרגום שני על מגילת אסתר, פרק ג--

Comment: I don't have a copy in front of me, but I thought it was written in Aramaic....

Comment: @msh210, It is, but this is probably copied from the hebrew translation "Patshegen Hak'tav", usually printed alongside it.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35991&st=&pgnum=26

Comment: According to that, the quotation in the answer is no quotation at all. (But perhaps there's another version. Gershon Gold, where did you get this from?)

Comment: @msh210, It's my bad. I assumed that @GershonGold was quoting the Targum directly and thus edited to show a more proper quote format. The text is probably from some other source quoting the Targum.