# Why do we specifically recall the greenery of Har Sinai on Shavuos?

Tags: minhag, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, shavuos, agriculture, har-sinai

While there are [several reasons](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7848/) why there is a custom to spread greenery in shul, one which is brought by the Mishnah Berurah (494:10) is that Har Sinai was covered with greenery.

Why is it specifically this point about Har Sinai which we recall on Shavuos? Why doesn’t anyone, for instance, blow the shofar in shul, since there was a shofar at Har Sinai?

Comment: Is your premise the Mishnah beruruahs reason? Because if we follow Magen avrahams reason, this no longer makes sense, because this then has nothing to do with har sinai

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Yes, obviously this question only applies according to the Mishnah Berurah.

Comment: I feel as though the fact that there exists other opinions significantly weakens this question